# How do I assign array of Objects as value to an Attribute in Apache NiFi

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

In Apache NiFi, My Mongo DB is returning Array of Objects as shown below

```
   [ 
     { fname:john,  
      city:Nyc 
      },
     { lname:doe,
      city:Nj
     }
   ]
```

I am trying to assign the entire array of Objects to an Attrbiute using **EvaluateJsonPath** Processor,

my  **EvaluateJsonPath** configuration is as shown below,but I am getting "**EvaluateJsonPath unable to return a scalar**" error.

I tried **$.*** in fullname value, tried changing return type to **Scalar** and **auto detect**. still I am getting the same error.

[image]

How do I assign the entire array of objects to an attribute in Apache NiFi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case,if any one is interested

**Changing Return type to Json** and Fullname value to **$.*** resolved the issue.